# AVR studio7 declaration error

Tags: avr, avr-studio7

i need your help

i am trying atmega128a using AVR studio 7

but one problem is there

when i control DDRB and PORTB into main()

it works fine

but if i control DDRB and PORTB out of main()

if becomes error

'expected identifier or '(' before volatile'

i just want to know that why always handing DDRB and PORTB is only in main()

here is my code

```
#define F_CPU 14745600UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

DDRB = 0xFF;
PORTB = 0x00;

int main(void)
{
    /* Replace with your application code */

    PORTB = 0x01;
    _delay_ms(300);
    while (1) 
    {
        PORTB <<= 1;

        _delay_ms(300);

        if(PORTB == 0x80){
            PORTB = 0x01;
            _delay_ms(300);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C is not a scripting language.  Any line of code that actually runs *must* be inside a function.  You can make a new function and call it from `main`.

Comment: but this code works in visual studio 2017
if you are right it might be not works in any other compiler and IDE
plz help me

Comment: I don't believe that code works in Visual Studio.  First of all, what would DDRD be defined as in VS?  I already did help you in my answer by telling you how you can structure your C program.  Are you having trouble following my suggestion?

Comment: Do you know how to write a new function and call it from `main`?  Can you give it a try?

Answer (score 1):

They need to be assigned inside of a function because they are macros that end up getting replaced with something that looks like this:

```
(*(volatile uint8_t *)<address>)
```

where `<address>` is a memory address that corresponds to the register that you are trying to access.  You are trying to cast and dereference a pointer, which is not a valid operation outside of a function.